# How to restrict Joomla smart search?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I got pulled in on an existing Joomla site (2.5.x) running K2. I'd like to restrict Joomla's smart search ONLY to K2 items. Nothing else. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the plugins for the other content types. But this is not a programming question.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a programming issue, where I'd need to go in and tweak something, or not. Turns out, it wasn't. Your advice worked beautifully. Thank you!